# После обновления centos 7 до версии 4.17.10-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 выходит ошибка

Tags: linux, centos6

После обновления centos 7 до версии 4.17.10-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 выходит ошибка Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not connect: Connection refused (g-io-error-quark, 39)

uname -a 
Linux alllibs.com 4.17.10-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Jul 25 15:25:01 EDT 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: судя по данным гугля, `4.17.10-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64` — это версия пакета с программой linux, а не версия дистрибутива centos. загрузите предыдущую версию программы linux. а про эту багрепорт напишите туда, откуда этот пакет взяли.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее речь идет о том, что обновилось ядро до 4.17.10-1 и оно с ошибкой.
Вариант тут при старте системы загрузиться со старого ядра. Если у вас система имеет монитор - при старте в меню выбрать пункт с ядром в списке ниже.
Потом поглядеть какие ядра установлены (в примере ниже у меня они еще 3*):

```
rpm -qa | grep kernel
kernel-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-693.17.1.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-862.2.3.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-862.6.3.el7.x86_64
kernel-3.10.0-862.3.3.el7.x86_64
```

и удалить, например во так (опять же цифры у вас будут другими)

```
yum remove kernel-3.10.0-693.21.1
```

Comment: Загрузил предыдущее ядро (Linux alllibs.com 3.10.0-693.2.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Sep 12 22:26:13 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux), все без изменений

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/254036/g-io-error-quark-39-error-when-stopping-dbus-service

Comment: видел тему, смотрел, данная служба пути имеет как нужно, другая балы с неверными путями, сделал ссылки как указано в теме, не заработало